# Why Benzene Cannot be chlorinated using HOCl?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

Why HOCl doesnt do the job please , can anyone show me the mechanism ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility:  When you chlorinate with, let us say, $\ce{Cl2 + FeCl3}$, you generate a "leaving group", $\ce{FeCl4^-}$, that comes off easily because it is highly polarizable and only weakly basic.  The $\ce{HOCl +H^+}$ combination would have to displace a more strongly basic and less polarizable water molecule.

Chlorination can be effected with hypochlorous acid by adding silver ion as another catalyst/co-reagent.  See [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Textbook_Maps/Organic_Chemistry/Book%3A_Basic_Principles_of_Organic_Chemistry_(Roberts_and_Caserio)/22%3A_Arenes%2C_Electrophilic_Aromatic_Substitution/22.04%3A_Electrophilic_Aromatic_Substitution).

Comment: Oscar Lanzi Phenol is brominated with bromine water .How do we explain this ?

Comment: A more activated ring, and bromide ion is the displaced species.